# Set Highcharts height dynamically while keeping the auto width

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm facing with a trouble when setting the height of a bar chart dynamically in highcharts.

I'm using following code to adjust the height according to the bar count of the chart.

chart.setSize(null, barsCount * 45 + 20, false);

I have passed null for the chart width since I want it to be adjusted according to the outer container. but I'm getting the following error.

attribute x: Expected length, "NaN".

Passing undefined also not worked for me.

Is there any way to set only the height of the chart?

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle and show us your code?

Comment: Here we go @EmreBolat http://jsfiddle.net/2q7zxcw9/  As you can see it give an error even though the functionality is fine.

Comment: I think that you can find here the answer on your question: http://forum.highcharts.com/highstock-usage/upgrade-highstock-error-t35956/

Comment: Updating highcharts to latest version resolved the issue